# distribution space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, distribution-theory

What are the differences between function spaces and distribution spaces? I was reading [enter link description here](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=9Q3HBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA323&lpg=PA323&dq=heat%20semigroup%20in%20Lp&source=bl&ots=bd299YTMQP&sig=Ho7RWqgXmfDWMpdC17iWLBE3R3Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwCDgKahUKEwi-sJqxhOLIAhVnF6YKHclrAIk#v=onepage&q=heat%20semigroup%20in%20Lp&f=false)

But I do not know what are these distribution spaces and how they differ from function spaces. Any examples are appreciated.

Comment: Look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)

Comment: All reasonable functions are distribitions; hence, all familiar function spaces are distribution spaces.